# perl rand lc/uc

Tags: perl, password-generator

I'm trying to get random lower case/upper case in my 42 chars password. Somehow
I instead get:

> ucclcjuczlclucmlc0lcdlc5lc0ucdlccucmucquc5ucslc4lckucxuctlcvlcquclucpuc0ucvlczucducauczlcauc7lciucmlcplcjucolchucmucpuc9lcilcqlck

Here is my code:

```
@a = (0 .. 9, 'a' .. 'z');
@case = ('lc','uc'); 
my $x = join '', map { scalar $case[rand(0-2)],  $a[int rand @a]}  0 .. 42;
print "$x\n";
```

Any Hints?

Comment: Why do you expect the string `'lc'` to somehow magically get turned into the builtin function with the same name?

Comment: maybe because it works in sh: `myfoo=$1
TR="tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'"
echo $myfoo | $TR`

Comment: According to you, `$tr = "uc"; print $tr, "abc";` should print `ABC`. That makes no sense.

Comment: Shell commands are interpreted, whereas Perl is compiled. Perl is done with the code before anything is assigned to `@case`, so the value of `@case` cannot be used as code. At least not without restarting the parser using `eval EXPR`.

Comment: What's `rand(-2)` suppose to do?

Answer (score 5):

Why not just select a random alphanumeric character (that, in the case of letters, can be upper or lower case)?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @chars=("a".."z","A".."Z",0..9);
my $password="";

foreach(1..42)
{
  #tack on a random alphanumeric character
  $password.=$chars[int(rand(@chars))] 
}

print $password . "\n";
```

If you want to make `lc` or `uc` an explicit part of the process, you can do something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @chars=("a".."z",0..9);

my $password="";

foreach(1..42)
{
  my $char=$chars[int(rand(@chars))];
  $char=uc($char) if rand() <0.5;
  $password.=$char;
}

print $password . "\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have strings (`uc` or `lc`) that you expect to be executed as code, but they are never passed to the parser. You could pass them to the parser by using `eval EXPR`, but that's not the right approach.

```
my @chars = ('0'..'9', 'a'..'z');
my $passwd =
   join '',
    map rand >= 0.5 ? uc : lc,
     map $chars[rand(@chars)],
      1..42;
```

Or better yet:

```
my @chars = ('0'..'9', 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z');
my $passwd =
   join '',
    map $chars[rand(@chars)],
     1..42;
```

Answer (score 5):

No sense in using `lc`and `uc` when providing a list of upper and lower case is as simple as it is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub random_pwd {
    my $length = shift;
    my @chars = (0 .. 9, 'a' .. 'z', 'A' .. 'Z');
    return join '', @chars[ map rand @chars, 0 .. $length ];
}
print random_pwd(42);
```

If you however wish to randomize caps in an already existing string, here's one way:

```
$str =~ s/(\w)/ rand() < 0.5 ? uc($1) : lc($1) /ge;
```

Somewhat stricter is using `[a-z]` instead of `\w` (which also includes numbers), but all you are losing is some redundant processing (e.g. `uc("L")` or `lc("2")`), which should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your code joins together the strings 'lc' or 'uc' with the random letters, rather than actually applying the lc or uc functions to the random letters. (You can't take a reference to built-in functions before Perl 5.16 anyway.)

Comment: Maybe not directly, but you can use `sub { uc($_[0]) }` instead of `\&CORE::uc` to such a reference.

Answer (score 2):

**iSn't CPan wOndERFuL?**

```
use Text::Capitalize;

print scramble_case "Isn't CPAN wonderful?";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already several good answers, I will present two more, one that looks like how you were thinking, and the second using CPAN

First, in the manner of the OP: make anonymous subroutines which return the `uc` or `lc` of their argument, then randomly invoke one or the other on a random character.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = (0 .. 9, 'a' .. 'z');
my @case = (sub{lc shift},sub{uc shift}); 
my $x = join '', map { $case[int rand(2)]->($a[int rand @a]) } 1 .. 42;
print "$x\n";
```

Ok, so now you have learned about function invoking. For your password generation, we take a quick look to CPAN and find [`String::Random`](http://p3rl.org/String%3a%3aRandom). It lets you generate random strings based on patterns.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use String::Random 'random_regex';

print random_regex('[a-zA-Z]{42}'), "\n";
```

The last time I ran this I got

```
LpvrMpylaaZTzmMbyBLiNQiwFZyKWWesVecvBWbLwu
```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably try something like the following one liner:

```
perl -le "print map { ('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9')[rand 62] } 1..42"
```

SXQtgMmzL7hsF9EZ2p9DrGg8BudNh4QWkOQn6UurPk

```
perl -le "print map { ('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9')[rand 62] } 1..42"
```

Rk6TJlBRkB3tS6fhmtXUNAmHSw04HNJTWCw2bhTcSl

For Linux you can replace " with ' and ' with ".

Source - catonmat.net